# Infimum of sum of two values.

Tags: real-analysis, summation, limsup-and-liminf, upper-lower-bounds

Let the function $f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R_{\ge 0}}$ be defined as
$$
f_{n}(x)=\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{i+j}\cos(\ln \frac{i}{j})}{(ij)^{x}}\quad \forall n\in\Bbb N
$$
There is given two different positive values: $x_{1},x_{2}$.

> For given natural $N$ find possibly the best lower bound of sum $F(N):=f_{N}(x_{1})+f_{N}(x_{2})$

And also:

> Find limit inferior of $F(n)$

How to in general solve that kind of problems ?(i mean to find limit inferior of sum of functions)

Regards.

EDIT:
My idea was to checking every pair of consecutive elements of this sequence i.e to find 
$$\max\{F(N),F(N+1)\}\quad \forall n\in\Bbb N$$
Is this true that $\inf F(N)>0$ ?

What if i ask about positivity of limit of $F(n)$ ?